# How can I see that $\sum_2^n \frac{1}{j} = \int_1^n \frac{1}{j}\ dj$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation, riemann-sum

Can your show how this comes about or give me pointers of investigation so can I work it out?  Thank you!

---

**EDIT1**: Various pointed out the equation is false, but that it can be taken as approximation.  Since no answered were added, I'd like to ask how I could start from the left hand side and construct an approximation to the sum by using the right hand side.  What steps should I take to see how to do that?

Comment: You can't because as written it's false. Unless you put in a ceiling function on $1/\lceil x \rceil$.

Comment: That's not true. It is approximately true, You can see why by seeing that the sum  is a Riemann sum for the integral on the right.

Comment: It already fails for $n=2$.

Comment: I'm interested in an approximation indeed.  I'm editing the question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Each of those already is an approximation to the other. There;s no need to "construct an approximation". You can find a better approximation to the integral by refining the Riemann sum. Perhaps the answer from @user108128 is what you want.

Comment: Perhaps would be better to ask for what $n$:
$$|\sum_{j=2}^n\dfrac{1}{j}-\int_1^n\dfrac{1}{j}dj|<\varepsilon$$

Comment: Do you think $1/2 = \ln 2?$

Comment: I most certainly think not, although I do see that they're not far apart: $\ln 2$ is approximately $0.69$ (IIRC), not too far from $0.5$.  So, yes, you put the question very well.  For what $n$ does the inequality hold.  I'll ask it as a new question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More tenuous, you can say
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{1}{j}
&=\ln n+\gamma+\varepsilon_n\\
\sum_{j=2}^n\dfrac{1}{j}
&=\int_1^n\dfrac{1}{j}dj\color{red}{+\gamma+\varepsilon_n}-1
\end{align}
$$
where $\varepsilon_n\sim\dfrac{1}{2n}$. You may see the details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence).

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{x}dx=\sum_{j=2}^n\int_{j-1}^j\frac{1}{x}dx$.  However $\int_{j-1}^j\frac{1}{x}dx \approx \frac{j-\frac{1}{2}}{j(j-1)}\approx \frac{1}{j}$, giving an approximation to the result you want.

The last step could be made a little clearer.  $\frac{1}{j-1}\gt \int_{j-1}^j\frac{1}{x}dx\gt \frac{1}{j}$.  Therefore $\int_{j-1}^j\frac{1}{x}dx\approx \frac{1}{j}$.